# Python XML parsing using schema with correct type inference

Tags: python, xml-parsing

Using an XML schema (xsd file) I would like to parse an XML document with correct type inference: so if the schema specifies an array (maxOccurs="unbounded", for example), the resulting element will be a python list (even if it has only one element).

I know lxml Objectifier can use a XML schema, but the result doesn't adhere to the types in the schema.

Answer (score 0):

XMLSchema enables parsing XML using a schema: http://xmlschema.readthedocs.io/en/latest/